# Is there a copy and paste stack or queue application for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, copy-paste

I'd like to keep my copy/paste history around (for a few items). Is there a tool which allows me to do it?

Comment: What has your research on the subject shown?

Comment: The internet is full of articles that talk about copy and paste but are entirely unrelated to my question

Answer (score 3):

There are many I'm sure, but [Flycut (Clipboard Manager)](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/flycut-clipboard-manager/id442160987?mt=12) seems to be one that fits the bill.

> Flycut is a clean and simple clipboard manager for developers. It
>   based on open source app called Jumpcut. Flycut is also open source:
>   http://github.com/TermiT/flycut

Answer (score 1):

> Clipboard History included with advanced options

http://www.machsoftwaredesign.com/clipboard.html

Based on what you were asking for this would be a viable solution.  What it sounds like you are asking for is a clipboard replacement.  That is, one that includes a history (you can Google this).

The other option is that you are looking for something that records when you cut and paste a file or folder.  If that is that case, I'm unaware of any software providing this functionality.